# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\User::id()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im starting with Laravel/Eloquent short ago. Coming from Java/Hibernate, but never mastered.Trying to open new ways. Using Laravel 8, latest version right now.
AFAIK, in java hibernate, you can declare id attribute in Model, link it via Hibernate annotations to DB builder, and, when you deploy the app it creates a bunch of tables and restrictions such as PK, FK, UNIQUE, etc (keeping it simple stupid).

But not in Laravel or so i think.
I get this error
[image: I get this error]

from User Model created by artisan, but slightly modified with some random attributes, but no static function id() inside[image: static function id()???]

This, the seeder
[image: Seeder]

This, the Factory in trouble, I guess, in $vend->id, and $comp->id.
Sellers and buyers extends User.
All Users can be both sellers and buyers, but can´t buy to themselves

[image]

What am I loosing? How to statically call an attribute of instantiated object? shoul I implement a static function like `return self::id`? but no id inside just in the tables seeded!!! Then should i put inside my Models an id attribute?

Sorry if it sounds dumb, so I am, and newbie too.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you do need to put a static method inside your model, but what you want to do with this id() method

Comment: I´m not sure what I want to make with it, it just claims, but i didn´t generate the call. It´s automatically loaded by Eloquent.

Comment: Can't see any line in the seeder which could throw the exception. Go through the factories and check if you have any reference to `id()` method in any of those factories.

Comment: try to post the code here instead of images, though in this question in does not matter much if code is in image or posted here

Comment: After $vend=Seller::has('products')->get()->random(); $vend is a Seller record. So in the next statement $vendor->id->random() doesn't make sense. $vendor->id is a single value and doesn't have random method. Also except method on collection should be defined with key, value. Comp=User::all()->except('id', $vend->id). Still can't find the line which would throw an error for `id()` on User

Comment: I'll keep an eye on that. BTW, I added to factory and model id attribute explicitily, but now records repeat PK, so can't go further on DB filling. I've been reading SO threads about, and they say it's about auto incrementing but set it and nothing changes. I will post further changes when magic comes around

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you want to get the user with Id X using laravel eloquent.

You are almost there. Laravel eloquent has build in functions for you so for example if you want to get the user with `Id = 5` you can do:

```
$user = App\Models\User::find(5);
```

Find filters based on id or you can create a normal query statement like:

```
$user = App\Models\User::where('id','=',5)->first();
```

If you want to use a different column in users model, for example the ones you added yourself the second option fits best for you.

Comment: No, I´m not trying to use find() by now, just seeding the tables with faker, but error throws out

Comment: @VidalM. Can you post the seed code what you are attempting

Comment: Yes please post your code, that will clear the things out. Edit your question for that.

Comment: maybe pluck('id')?? Don´t think so, it´s not related to User

Comment: seeder reloaded. My bad replicating lines^_^but no solution to q question found